# python manage.py makemigrations no module named error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Thats the error after using command from title,

```
    (SrdW) C:\Users\DELL>python manage.py makemigrations blog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\SrdW\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py"
, line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\SrdW\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py"
, line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\SrdW\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in se
tup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\SrdW\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112,
 in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\SrdW\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, i
n import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__
init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\blog\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Post(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\blog\models.py", line 6, in Post
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Thats mysite/settings.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',]
```

Also blog\models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I set up virtual enviroment end creat project mysite than startapp blog and when i try to makemirgations this error occured, im complet beginner, where is the source of error? im using windows/ python 3.x and django 2.0.1

Comment: Comma missing between `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` and `'blog.apps.BlogConfig'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Thx, i add the comma, error text changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just added this and it solved the problem.

```
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
```

Comment: Yes, `on_delete` is a required parameter from Django 2.0 on.